# How does symbol binding work for shared libraries in linux

Tags: c++, linux, binding, dynamic-linking

When compiling a cpp program with g++ -O0 I noticed that my binary does not contain the symbol for the empty string (basic_string):
_S_empty_rep_storage
When I do compile this same program with -O2 I notice that the aforementioned symbol is indeed contained within the binary as  follows (using nm on the bin):

**00000000006029a0 V _ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE@@GLIBCXX_3.4**

My application uses several .so (dynamic libraries) and when my aplication loads I notice that several of these .so files bind as follows (I set LD_DEBUG=all and ran my program):

```
 28596: binding file /home/bbazso/usr/local/lib/mydynamiclib.so [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
 28596: binding file /home/bbazso/usr/local/lib/mydynamiclib.so [0] to /home/bbazso/workspace/mytestapplication [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
 28596: binding file /home/bbazso/workspace/mytestapplication [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE' [GLIBCXX_3.4]**
```

But I also noticed that one of my .so only binds as follows:

```
  28087:    binding file /home/bbazso/usr/local/lib/anotherdynamiclib.so [0] to /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 [0]: normal symbol `_ZNSs4_Rep20_S_empty_rep_storageE' [GLIBCXX_3.4]
```

but never binds to the binary (mytestapplication) as shown above for the  mydynamiclib.so.

So I was wondering what this actually means?  Does this mean that anotherdynamiclib.so will use a different symbol for the empty string above than the rest of the application?  I guess what I'm really asking is how does symbol binding work in the context of the example above?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid I don't fully understand your question but you might find an answer in a Ulrich Drepper paper called [How to write shared libraries](http://people.redhat.com/drepper/dsohowto.pdf). It is the best I know regarding how symbols with elf executables in Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I have difficulty parsing your question. If you included a small snippet of example code that you are compiling it might help.

> > I notice that the aforementioned symbol is indeed contained within the binary as follows
> >     It depends what you mean by "contained in". There is an entry for that symbol in the symbol table, but it is an external symbol, not a symbol that your application is "exporting". Note the @@GLIBCXX_3.4 in the name. The actual location of the symbol is in GLIBCXX (which looks like it actually resolves to libstdc++).

From your output, nm does not appear to actually show the ST_BIND information (part of the st_info field in the El32_Sym/Elf64_Sym structures). This is the information that determines how the linker treats the binding of the symbol. Can you run 
readelf -s YOURBINNAME
It will show the bindings.